# sharing and Reusing Tensorflow variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I have been struggling with an issue for few days now and I can not understand whats going on , I have developed an seq2seq model , in one function I create some Tensorflow operations and variables then return them to the caller , I would like that function to reuse all the variables and no matter what I do in scopes I do not seem to get it right , below is the function :

```
def create_complete_cell(rnn_size,num_layers,encoder_outputs_tr,batch_size,encoder_state , beam_width ):

    with tf.variable_scope("InnerScope" , reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        encoder_outputs_tr =tf.contrib.seq2seq.tile_batch(encoder_outputs_tr, multiplier=beam_width) 
        encoder_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.tile_batch(encoder_state, multiplier=beam_width) 
        batch_size =  batch_size * beam_width 
        dec_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([create_cell(rnn_size) for _ in range(num_layers)])

        attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention(num_units=rnn_size, memory=encoder_outputs_tr ) 

        attn_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(dec_cell, attention_mechanism , attention_layer_size=rnn_size , output_attention=False)
        attn_zero = attn_cell.zero_state(batch_size , tf.float32 )
        attn_zero = attn_zero.clone(cell_state = encoder_state)
    return attn_zero ,  attn_cell
```

and below is the code calling the above function :

```
with tf.variable_scope('scope' ):
    intial_train_state , train_cell = create_complete_cell(rnn_size,num_layers,encoder_outputs_tr,batch_size,encoder_state , 1  )
with tf.variable_scope('scope' ,reuse=True):
    intial_infer_state , infer_cell = create_complete_cell(rnn_size,num_layers,encoder_outputs_tr,batch_size,encoder_state , beam_width  )
print("intial_train_state" , intial_train_state)
print("intial_infer_state" , intial_infer_state)
```

the print outputs the below :

first print command outputs:

```
('intial_train_state', AttentionWrapperState(cell_state=(LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_1:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>), LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_2:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_3:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>), LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_4:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_5:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>), LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_6:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_7:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>)), attention=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/AttentionWrapperZeroState/zeros_1:0' shape=(100, 512) dtype=float32>, time=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/AttentionWrapperZeroState/zeros:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, alignments=<tf.Tensor 'scope/InnerScope/AttentionWrapperZeroState/zeros_2:0' shape=(100, ?) dtype=float32>, alignment_history=()))
```

and the second print commands outputs :

```
('intial_infer_state', AttentionWrapperState(cell_state=(LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_1:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>), LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_2:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_3:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>), LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_4:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_5:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>), LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_6:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_7:0' shape=(?, 512) dtype=float32>)), attention=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/AttentionWrapperZeroState/zeros_1:0' shape=(300, 512) dtype=float32>, time=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/AttentionWrapperZeroState/zeros:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, alignments=<tf.Tensor 'scope_1/InnerScope/AttentionWrapperZeroState/zeros_2:0' shape=(300, ?) dtype=float32>, alignment_history=()))
```

I was expecting that both output would be the same since I'm reusing the variables but as you can see that for example in the first variable the output has something like this 
**scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_1:0**

and in the second variable

**scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_1:0**

I do not know why _1 is added to **scope** in the second call , and I'm a bit confused if the variable is being shared or not , and if not  what should I do to return the same variable ( shared)  .

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that this question is left unanswered , I'm just reposting the answer I got on the same subject from Tensorflow GitHub site .

source : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12916

to summarize , the values 
scope_1/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_1:0
scope/InnerScope/tile_batch_1/Reshape_1:0

are not variable names , instead these are just the nodes created by tensorflow for the reshape operation , each Operation in Tensroflow graph has its unique name .

this does not mean that the variables are not shared